# MXGraph: edges are not redrawn when they are moved

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mxgraph

this might be a stupid question and I know it is hard to tell without a look at the code... However I have an issue and maybe somebody can point me toward the right direction.

I am developing a javascript mxGraph application integrated with Angular7. I'm using a modified version of the ports.html example.

If I add two nodes and connect them, then I export it in XML with this code:

```
var enc = new mx.mxCodec(mx.mxUtils.createXmlDocument());
var node = enc.encode(editor.graph.getModel());
xml = mx.mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node);
```

I am able to save it correctly and then reload it.

However if I move the connection as shown in the image here:

[image: Before exporting XML]

the connection is not redrawn in the graph, although it is present in the model as cell:

[image: After importing XML]

Here a screenshot of the model, as you can see, both connections are present but just the one that I didn't move is drawn:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution... It is somehow related to this past issue that I had: [MxCodec decode function not working with XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804525/mxcodec-decode-function-not-working-with-xml)

As when an edge is moved it creates an Array of mxPoints, which are not decoded properly because of missing ctor in window. The solution was adding to the window:

```
window['mxPoint'] = mx.mxPoint;
```